# Making a sorted array of user's input

Tags: ruby

I'm learning Ruby with 'Learn to Program' by Chris Pine. On chapter 10 I should write a program where the user types as many words as he like and when he's done, he can just press `Enter` on an empty line and exit.
I came up with this:

```
puts "Type whatever you want!"
index = 0 
word = ''
array = []
while word != nil
    word << gets.chomp
    array[index] = word
    index = index + 1
end
puts ''
puts array.sort
```

But that doesn't work. What did I miss? Is there another way I could define `word` without having to repeat it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `word` will not have `nil` value. It will be an empty string. So you need to check for that:

```
while word != ""

# or even better
while !word.empty?
```

Also, you are adding everything to your `word`. You probably want to assign to it instead:

```
word = gets.chomp
```

**Per author's comment:**

```
begin 
  # your code here 
end while !word.empty?

# OR more readable
begin 
  # your code here 
end until word.empty?
```

Comment: I tried with '!word.empty?' and now it exits immediately without typing in anything. I guess the problem is with 'word = " " ' at the beginning of the code. I just don't know how to define this variable in another way.

Comment: Use `expressin while` loop. I'll add an example to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there's a simpler solution, if I'm reading the question correctly.

You could do something like this:

`user_input = gets.chomp.split(" ").sort`

ex)

input: `bananas clementine zebra tree house plane mine`

output: `["bananas", "clementine", "house", "mine", "plane", "tree", "zebra"]`

Comment: The OP wanted the users to input the words one on each line.  I don't know how important that was.

Answer (score 0):

Using `loop` might simplify the code:

```
a = []

loop do
  input = gets.chomp
  if input.empty?
    break
  else
    a << input
  end
end

a.sort!
puts a
```

Comment: Added a.sort! to my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple loop that you could do just for kicks:

```
arr = []
arr << $_.strip until gets =~ /^\s*$/
puts arr.sort
```

`$_` is a special variable that evaluates to the last input read from `STDIN`. So basically this reads "Call `gets` and check if the input is just spaces. If it is then break out of the loop, otherwise append the last input with whitespace removed value onto the array and continue looping."

Or even more fun, a one liner:

```
puts [].tap {|arr| arr << $_.strip until gets =~ /^\s*$/}.sort
```

Basically same thing as above except using `tap` to initialize the variable.

**To answer your questions:**

> Is there another way I could define word without having to repeat it?

Use [side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) of assignment. In ruby when you assign a variable the return value of that assignment is the assigned variable, as in:

```
irb(main):001:0> (variable = 2) == 2
=> true
```

The idea would be to put the assignment in the your conditional. If I were to write something like this in a comprehensible loop, as opposed to those above, I'd write something like this:

```
arr = []
while !(word = gets.strip).empty?
  arr << word
end
puts arr.sort
```